# Spark - Find total occurrence of each distinct value in two different columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to find the total occurrence of each distinct value in both col1 and col2

```
col1   col2    
a        a      
a        c
```

Result

```
Id       count
a          3    
c          1
```

If this is SQL, I will do something like this

```
  select id, sum(count) from ( Select  col1 as id, count(*) as count from table group by col1 union all Select  col2 as id, count(*) as count from table group by col2) group by id
```

I am new to Spark. I need help to find an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried running that very sql using `spark.sql("...")`?

Comment: I have to do it in scala and I not supposed to use spark.sql.

Comment: Can you provide a lot of code with initial data values?

Comment: Can some one help to edit this question to add table of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#explode) function on an array that contains the two columns, as follow:

```
input
  .select("col1", "col2")
  .withColumn("Id", explode(array(col("col1"), col("col2"))))
  .groupBy("Id")
  .count()
  .show()
```

That will print:

```
+---+-----+
|Id |count|
+---+-----+
|c  |1    |
|a  |3    |
+---+-----+
```

This solution prevents spark to compute two times the input dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `union` `col1` and `col2` as a new `id` column, then group by it:

```
df.select(col("col1").alias("id"))
  .unionAll(df.select(col("col2").alias("id")))
  .groupBy("id")
  .count()
  .show()
```

Which prints:

```
+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  c|    1|
|  a|    3|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ernest. Is this the efficient way to get want i want?